# Why re.findall('(ab)+', 'abab') returns ['ab']= meanwhile re.findall('(ab)+?', 'abab') returns ['ab', 'ab']?

Tags: python, regex

My python version is  `2.7.6`

I know that `+?` is the non-greedy version of `+`.
so that  `re.findall('(ab)+?', 'abab')` will match as less `ab` as it can.
The result `['ab', 'ab']` thus make sense.

But when comes to the greedy version match `re.findall('(ab)+', 'abab')`,  it confused me.
I thought the greedy version should match as much `ab` as it can.
Thus I shall got `['abab']` as the result.
But I got `['ab']` instead !

In the re.findall()'s help info, it says:

```
Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
has more than one group.

Empty matches are included in the result.
```

Here I got two group, the default `group0` for the whole RE, and my specified `(ab)` as `group1`.

So I did the following investigation:

```
In [21]: ng = re.search('(ab)+?', 'abab')

In [22]: g = re.search('(ab)+', 'abab')

In [23]: ng.group(0)
Out[23]: 'ab'

In [24]: ng.group(1)
Out[24]: 'ab'

In [25]: g.group(0)
Out[25]: 'abab'

In [26]: g.group(1)
Out[26]: 'ab'
```

It is crystal clear that `re` module will match `'abab'` as group0 and `'ab'` as group1 for the greedy search.
But why I got `['ab']` instead of `['abab', 'ab']` when doing `findall()` operation?
Beause `'abab'` contains `ab` so they were overlapped, and `findall()` only return the last match in this situation?

With this question, I did the following test:

```
In [30]: g = re.findall('[A-z](ab)+', 'ababdab')

In [31]: g
Out[31]: ['ab', 'ab']

In [32]: dg = re.search('[A-z](ab)+', 'ababdab')

In [33]: dg.groups()
Out[33]: ('ab',)

In [34]: dg.group()
Out[34]: 'bab'
```

Now I'm totally out of my mind now.
How does findall works here?
Why???

Comment: **Warning: Do not use the range `[A-z]` in regexes.**  It matches all the  ASCII letters as you expect, but it also matches several punctuation characters that happen to lie between `Z` and `a` numerically.

Answer (score 3):

There's a subtlety here - touched on in Jerry's answer, but not stated clearly.

You expected `re.findall('(ab)+', 'abab')` to tell you about *both* the implicit "group 0" for what the entire regex matched, *and* "group 1" for the parentheses. **That's not how it works.** If there are capturing parentheses, `findall`'s list *only* contains the groups for the capturing parentheses.  Observe:

```
>>> re.findall('(?:ab)+', 'abab') # no capture, reports group 0
['abab']
>>> re.findall('(ab)+', 'abab')   # one capture, reports _only_ group 1
['ab']
>>> re.findall('((ab)+)', 'abab') # two captures, reports both groups 1 and 2
[('abab', 'ab')]                  # (but still not group 0)
```

The documentation could stand to be clearer about this.  It assumes you understand that "group 0" doesn't really count as a group.  But this is how RE libraries have worked for decades.

Answer (score 1):

`findall` is working just like it should be working:

1. It gives all the matches within a string into a result list if there are no capture groups.
2. If there is one capture group, it will return a list of the capture groups only.
3. If there are more than one capture group, a list of tuples will be returned, with 1 tuple containing the capture groups for one match.

Next, the MatchObject returns the last captured group whenever there is a repetition of the group. It is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

> If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> m = re.match(r"(..)+", "a1b2c3")  # Matches 3 times.
> >>> m.group(1)                        # Returns only the last match.
> 'c3'
> ```

So a combination of both phenomenons give the result you are experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look:

```
In [13]: re.findall('(ab)', 'ababab')
Out[13]: ['ab', 'ab', 'ab']

In [14]: re.findall('(ab)+?', 'ababab')
Out[14]: ['ab', 'ab', 'ab']

In [15]: re.findall('(ab)+', 'ababab')
Out[15]: ['ab']
```

`In[13]` is equivalent to `In[14]`. Both patterns will match each `ab` group. However, `In[15]` will match all `ab` contiguous repetitions, regardless their number.

The `[A-z](ab)+` pattern means that you want all `ab` contiguous repetitions that start with a letter `[A-z]`. The first group that matches it in `ababdab` is `bab`: it starts with `b` which is in [A-z], then there is a following `ab` group that ends at `d`, which starts the very next matching group.

```
In [20]: re.findall('[A-z](ab)+', 'XababXabXab')
Out[20]: ['ab', 'ab', 'ab']
```

Comment: See my comment under the question about **`[A-z]`**.  I know you just cut-n-pasted it from the OP's code, but you should always lookout for errors like that and correct them while you're answering. (We're full-service know-it-alls.)  By using them without comment, you're effectively endorsing them.  ("Well, this fellow seems to know what he's doing, and he uses `[A-z]`. Why shouldn't we?")

Comment: I don't think whether the `[A-z]` ranges should or not be used in regex  matters to the original question and to the test cases presented. Actually, it is quite irrelevant to them.

Comment: So you're saying it's okay to use `[A-z]` in this case because you know the string doesn't contain any square brackets, backslashes, carets, underscores or backticks?  And when the next regex beginner comes along and reads your answer, how are they supposed to know that's what you meant?  It is **never** okay to use `[A-z]` in a regex.

Comment: I'm saying that even if the string contains square brackets, backslashes, carets, underscores or backticks, it just doesn't matter for the question asked or the answer given. You are treating a different subject than the one asked. If you want to highlight this, ok, but I did rather not. My answer is not less valid because of this.

Comment: Your answer **is** less valid for using `[A-z]`.  `[A-Za-z]` is a perfect fit here, there's no excuse for not using it.  Using `[A-z]` instead is like walking around with an open wound.